# Android Emulator: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

Tags: android, xamarin

I hope you are doing well.
I am working on Xamarin Forms. I am getting this error "No Network Security Config specified, using platform default", while I send HttpClient request in my Android Emulator despite being having network_security_config.xml under App.Android/Resource/xml, It works fine on android device.
following is the code network_security_config.xml file contains:

```
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system"/>
      <certificates src="user"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</network-security-config>
```

**In my Manifest file, I have following code.**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:targetSandboxVersion="1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app71" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="Meha" android:icon="@drawable/logo_pink"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <application android:largeHeap="true" />
</manifest>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What the API level of the emulator that you are testing on?

Comment: emulator is using API level 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your `network_security_config.xml` like below :

```
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and the `manifest` like :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:targetSandboxVersion="1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.app71" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <application android:label="Meha" android:icon="@drawable/logo_pink" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true"></application>
</manifest>
```

as the [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) said,

The default configuration for apps targeting **Android 9 (API level 28) and higher** is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
  <trust-anchors>
    <certificates src="system" />
  </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

The default configuration for apps targeting **Android 7.0 (API level 24) to Android 8.1 (API level 27)** is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
   <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
   </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

The default configuration for apps targeting **Android 6.0 (API level 23) and lower** is as follows:

```
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
  <trust-anchors>
     <certificates src="system" />
     <certificates src="user" />
  </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
```

Comment: I am using Android 9 API 28, I am getting back the same error.

Comment: @ShaurBinTalibs try to move the properties of application tag into the same one,like my update above.

Comment: Error is gone but still http request has no response. It has response on android device but not on the emulator.

Comment: @ShaurBinTalib i think it is another question,maybe you could open a new question and show some codes what you are doing.